# stream voice through wifi - android

Tags: android

I'm working on entry phone. The entry phone is sending to me voice and video through rtsp protocol so I can simply get voice and video from camera on my device. But I have no idea how to send a voice to that device. Is there anything that would help me send and receive audio in the same time (something like a call)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct you want video calls. Just like sipdroid app. It is an open source project look at VideoCamera.java class in this project.

http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/

Comment: yes something like that, but is there any other way to send and receive voice between 2 devices? It doesn't need to send a video just the sound, is it possible?

Comment: Yes sipdroid also support only voice. It have so many codecs included in it, except G729.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful tip and i will try sipdroid. But I heard that the SIP is very slow and there may be delays. Do you know other methods to achieve such connection?

Comment: Android 2.3+ provide apis for you for the same work. I recommend looking at this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html